# Creating the installer for the eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse-plugin

We have created the eclipse plugins and create the executable for the plugins.But how can we create the installer for this eclipse product instead of the executable.

Comment: Do you mean you have created a new RCP? [Eclipse Ooomph](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Oomph/article.html) is one option.

Comment: from rcp product can we create the installer using oomph

Comment: Eclipse itself is an RCP and uses the Oomph installer so it must be possible. I haven't used Oomph myself.